# Issue with wrapping select element using 'DOMNodeInserted' in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap each select element in `<div class="select-box"></div>`  when they are inserted in a `div` having id "hook", the data is inserted using some ajax request that is not in my control.

It works but some unwanted divs `<div class="select-box"></div>` are appearing and an error occurs:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

**What I want:**

1. Prevent these unwanted divs that are highlighted in red color above the input type text.
2. Is there any alternate of DOMNodeInserted available for better browser support.

Here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/dmpak/pen/rNaGyPW

HTML code

```
<div id="data">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>

    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hook').on('DOMNodeInserted',function() {
        $('#hook > select').each(function(e) {
            selectUi($(this));
        });
    });

    //START of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
    setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
        $('#hook').html($('#data').html());
      }, 1000);
    //END of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
});

function selectUi(thatSelect) {
  thatSelect.wrap('<div class="select-box"></div>');
}
```

CSS code

```
.select-box{
  width 100%
  background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#data{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the call to `selectUi` is inserting a `div` inside `#hook`, so the event handler gets called again, which then calls `selectUi` again, inserting another `div`, so the event handler gets called etc. etc. You can work around this by disabling the event handler when it is called e.g.

```
  $('#hook').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    $('#hook').off('DOMNodeInserted');
    $('#hook > select').each(function(e) {
      selectUi($(this));
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hook').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    $('#hook').off('DOMNodeInserted');
    $('#hook > select').each(function(e) {
      selectUi($(this));
    });
  });

  //START of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('#hook').html($('#data').html());
    }, 1000);
  //END of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
});

function selectUi(thatSelect) {
  thatSelect.wrap('<div class="select-box"></div>');
}
```

```css
.select-box {
  width 100% background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hook">
</div>
<div id="data">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>

  First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
</div>
```

If you need to use the event handler again, consider using `.one` instead of `.on`, which will prevent it being called more than once for that event:

```
function wrapSelect() {
  $('#hook > select').each(function(e) {
    selectUi($(this));
  });
  $('#hook').one('DOMNodeInserted', wrapSelect);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hook').one('DOMNodeInserted', wrapSelect);
});
```

```js
function wrapSelect() {
  $('#hook > select').each(function(e) {
    selectUi($(this));
  });
  $('#hook').one('DOMNodeInserted', wrapSelect);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hook').one('DOMNodeInserted', wrapSelect);

  //START of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('#hook').html($('#data').html());
    }, 1000);
  //END of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
});

function selectUi(thatSelect) {
  thatSelect.wrap('<div class="select-box"></div>');
}
```

```css
.select-box {
  width 100% background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hook">
</div>
<div id="data">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>

  First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
</div>
```

In terms of broader browser support than the `DOMNodeInserted` event, you can look into [`Mutation Observers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which are supported in the current versions of almost all browsers.

```js
const config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

const wrapSelect = function(mutationList, observer) {
  observer.disconnect();
  for (let mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
        if (node.nodeName == 'SELECT')
          selectUi($(node));
      }
    }
  }
  observer.observe(hook, config);
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(wrapSelect);

$(document).ready(function() {
  const hook = document.querySelector("#hook");
  observer.observe(hook, config);

  //START of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('#hook').html($('#data').html());
    }, 1000);
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('#hook').append($('#data').html());
    }, 5000);
  //END of function that is not in my control, It may be some ajax request
});

function selectUi(thatSelect) {
  thatSelect.wrap('<div class="select-box"></div>');
}
```

```css
.select-box {
  width 100% background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hook">
</div>
<div id="data">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>

  First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @Nick for your time and effort, what about my 2nd point `Is there any alternate of DOMNodeInserted available for better browser support.`

Comment: @Syed you can use `MutationObserver`, which is supported by current versions of all browsers. See my edit.

Comment: Mutation Observers is also not supported by Opera Mini.

Comment: @Syed Ah - I didn't notice that Opera Mini was missing from the list of tested browsers on the documentation page. Perhaps you can use `DOMNodeInserted` for that browser - although it is deprecated so not a long term solution